# Why can't I use method return as a pointer in Java?

Tags: java

Solved, thanks. I actually added head.next to my head.child's last node, so the next run of lastNode returned different pointer.

In the following code, the commented code gave different result, why?

I was expecting the same behavior.

```
            Node p = lastNode(head.child); //Define a extra pointer
            p.next = head.next;
            if(head.next!=null) head.next.prev = p;
```

```
            //lastNode(head.child).next = head.next; // Not Working
            //head.next.prev = lastNode(head.child);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including all the variable declarations, etc. thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean? The marked line is at least syntactically correct. Is it possible here that the two invocations of ```lastNode(head.child)``` return different resutls?

Comment: how should we know what `lastNode` is doing? we only have its name. And how do you know it is not working?

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it. I actually added something to head.child's lastNode. 
How can I close this question?

Comment: There's a delete button right below the tags.

Comment: BTW "close question"? this is not a ticket system or so, you can  accept an answer if it answers the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Java. In the first example you call `lastNode` once and store the result in `p`. In your second example, you call `lastNode` twice, but after the first call, you add a new last node to your list, so the return value is different the second time!

Answer (score 0):

The second calculation of `lastNode(head.child)` after you change `lastNode(head.child).next` gives you the new last node. You must keep a pointer to the old last node in order to update the `prev` of the new last node.